# How to make div and button same size?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why div is not same size :/

Size should be the same bettwen components, based on text size.

[image]

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-surf-8fo9v?file=/src/App.tsx).

```
import * as React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Select>Aa</Select>
      <Button>Aa</Button>
      <Input />
    </div>
  );
}

const Button = styled.button`
  box-sizing: content-box;
  min-height: 1.4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
`;
const Input = styled.input`
  box-sizing: content-box;
  min-height: 1.4rem;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px 0;
`;
const Select = styled.div`
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to give each of them the same height. Then you have to reset the margins or you can give them all the same margin.. Also `box-sizing: border-box;` is necessary.

```css
button {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  min-height: 1.4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
}

input {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  min-height: 1.4rem;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px blue;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div,
button,
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<span style="display:flex">
  <input/>
  <div>Div</div>
  <button>Button</button>
 </span>
```

Comment: i can't give them fixed height because height desided by text content.

Comment: @RTW Okay, I removed the height and they're still the same size.

Answer (score -1):

Try placing the button inside the Div and change the height to 100%.

Comment: I can't do that for pure components. I need to do something with div.